# iPhone AdMob integration in already launched App

Tags: iphone, ios, admob

I have already launched application in iPhone and now I want to integrate `AdMob` in it.
How to start with, I don't know
do I need to create new provisioning profile in iTunes or what?
And how get `AdMob` id from iTunes and after integrating `AdMob` how to launch app again?
Please Help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to create any new provisioning profile for that just create with new version and upload again with AdMob.To add AdMob first we need to register in www.admob.com site.For Registration just follow these steps.

1. Login to www.admob.com.
2. Goto Sites & Apps.
3. Under sites & Apps select a site or app type.
4. Select iPhone App and full fill the details.

   After filling details you will provide with Admob id and SDk. you can download the AbMob SDK, it is required for publishing Ads and drag drop into the Xcode project and use that Admob id as publisher id in your code.

   For more information check this[link](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/how-to-admob-integrate-in-your-application-in-iphone/) and[link2](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals) you will get sample codes.
   Hope it will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

1). Do i need to create new provisioning profile - `No, you can use your existing distribution profile for upload new version of your app.`

2). how get AdMob id - [Please refer this link](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/)

3). how to launch app again - You need to create an version of your app. [More](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/8_AddingNewApps/AddingNewApps.html).

Answer (score 0):

now you can use **AdMob mediation**

Best tutorial of AdMob mediation

[AdMob_Mediation_Demo](https://github.com/111vandana/AdMob_Demo/archive/master.zip)

You can download it and use it in your project